# mysqli dynamic update query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

With this query I update images fields in database:

```
$sql = $connection->prepare('UPDATE ads img1 = ?, img2 = ?, img3 = ? WHERE id = ?');
$sql->bind_param("ssss", $nameImg1, $nameImg2, $nameImg3, $id);
```

But this work fine if user update all 3 images, not only one or two. if user change just one image, for example change `img2`, `img1` and `img3` going to update to empty value because I use this condition:

```
$img1 = $_POST["img-1-val"];
$img2 = $_POST["img-2-val"];
$img3 = $_POST["img-3-val"];

if($img1 != 'NULL'){
$nameImg1 = $date.'_'.$adsid.'_1';
} 

if($img2 != 'NULL'){
$nameImg2 = $date.'_'.$adsid.'_2';
} 

if($img3 != 'NULL'){
$nameImg3 = $date.'_'.$adsid.'_3';
}
```

in `html`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="img-1-val" value="NULL"/> 
<!-- this already has image -->
<input type="hidden" name="img-2-val"/>
<input type="hidden" name="img-3-val"/>
```

If each image has image, value is `NULL` if there is no image set, it is empty, if user change any image, it set `base64` value.

But the main problem is, I don't want to update any `img` field in database if `$_POST` return NULL as value, already it update all fields, img1, img2, img3,and this cause of removing previously data. **How can I update database field if value not equal to NULL?**

---

Consider these codes run in edit page.
Also my problem is `mysqli` query not `if` condition.

Comment: Check with `if($img1 != '')` for all your images I think so.

Comment: @Virb Still with that query, all img fields going to update, I just want update those has non `NULL` value.

Comment: Have you checked with `isset`? For e.g. `if((isset($img1)) && ($img1 != ''))`

Comment: @Virb No, forget if condition, just look at the mysqli query, it going to update all fields, img1, img2, img3. I just want to run update query for those has not value equal to `NULL`

Comment: So, check out my answer below and tell if it is working or not according to me.

Comment: Though, I recommend @chintan's answer for better structure.

Comment: Did you get your answer @tour travel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have to just check with different variable with query.

This will check one by one image and if all the images have values then it will update all three images otherwise one by one.
This may help.

```
if((isset($img1)) && ($img1 != 'NULL')){
    $nameImg1 = $date.'_'.$adsid.'_1';
    $sql = $connection->prepare('UPDATE ads img1 = ? WHERE id = ?');
    $sql->bind_param("ss", $nameImg1, $id);
} 

if((isset($img2)) && ($img2 != 'NULL')){
    $nameImg2 = $date.'_'.$adsid.'_2';
    $sql = $connection->prepare('UPDATE ads img2 = ? WHERE id = ?');
    $sql->bind_param("ss", $nameImg2, $id);
} 

if((isset($img3)) && ($img3 != 'NULL')){
    $nameImg3 = $date.'_'.$adsid.'_3';
    $sql = $connection->prepare('UPDATE ads img3 = ? WHERE id = ?');
    $sql->bind_param("ss", $nameImg3, $id);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this can be a solution, But I'm wondering, Is there any solution to avoid use three separate query?  I mean, just use one query but with your current logic. You know what? If user change all 3 images, this going to run three query.

Comment: @tourtravel: Well, according to me, not possible. Because one update query will fired all three variable's value if there is a value or not. And that you have to check with PHP itself.

Comment: Ok, so let me try your example.

Comment: Just update your answer with `SET` I missed it on my answer. I prefer to use your answer, because I should use prepared statement.

Answer (score 3):

You can make your update query dynamic like this :

```
/* function to build SQL UPDATE string */
function build_sql_update($table, $data, $where)
{
    $cols = array();

    foreach($data as $key=>$val) {
        if($val != NULL) // check if value is not null then only add that colunm to array
        {
           $cols[] = "$key = '$val'"; 
        }
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE $table SET " . implode(', ', $cols) . " WHERE $where";

    return($sql);
}
```

In this way, only those columns will be updated which has valid values.

Comment: A little confused, in you example `$data` is array, right? but `img-1-val` or etc are string, should convert those to an array?  also how to check if not null here? can you update your answer?

Comment: And another problem is, I want to run this in prepared statement , any way?

Comment: $_POST can be treated as $data. I have updated the answer to check if a value is null